# How to get list of all git remotes present on my machine?

Tags: git, heroku, dvcs

I have multiple apps configures on heroku and GitHub.

When I added heroku remotes, I used these aliases:

> app1
>
> app1-staging
>
> app2
>
> app2-staging
>
> ... etc.

Now, one of the remote staging name was somehow misspelled and I closed the terminal window.

Is there a way to list/find all heroku remotes I have configured on my system?

**Note:** I tried `heroku apps` and it gives me apps name but not the remote names.

Answer (score 5):

"[`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)" modifies the local config of a repository, ie the `config` file under the `.git` directory of a repo.

That means there is no "central place" where to query all your repo: you need to:

- search for all `.git` directory on your local machine or your heroku instance, and
- do a `git remote -v` in each one to see the remotes defined.